# Deno: Cannot find module "https://deno.land/x/fiona"

Tags: typescript, deno

I know `Deno` was recently release but I want to implement a presentation using it to show some nice features and I had this problem when I tried to import some of it [third-party modules](https://deno.land/x/).

I tried it four ways:

```
import Fiona from 'https://deno.land/x/fiona';
import Fiona from 'https://deno.land/x/fiona/index.js';
import * as Fiona from 'https://deno.land/x/fiona/index.js';
import { Fiona } from 'https://deno.land/x/fiona/core/index.js';
```

Unfortunately I still get the error `Cannot find module "https://deno.land/x/fiona"`. Can someone help?

Comment: https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/typescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The imports that works on that package are:

```
import Fiona from 'https://deno.land/x/fiona/deno/index.js'

const seeded = Fiona(2983938);

const data = seeded.object({
    name: Fiona.Fullname,
    age: Fiona.Number({ max: 100 }),
});

console.log(data); // { name: "Miss Fiona Moon", age: 1 }
```

or

```
import bootstrap from 'https://deno.land/x/fiona/bootstrap.js'

const Fiona = bootstrap();
const seeded = Fiona(2983938);

const data = seeded.object({
    name: Fiona.Fullname,
    age: Fiona.Number({ max: 100 }),
});

console.log(data); // { name: "Miss Fiona Moon", age: 1 }
```

---

```js
import Fiona from 'https://deno.land/x/fiona/index.js';
```

The above import fails with:

```
error: relative import path "randexp" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../ Imported from "https://deno.land/x/fiona/index.js"
```

Because there's an error in `index.js` since the package is doing:

```
import RandExp from 'randexp'
```

Which isn't valid for Deno. That's the `index.js` for Node.js

---

```js
import Fiona from 'https://deno.land/x/fiona';
```

This one fails because unlike Node.js, Deno does not load `index.js` by default when you import a folder.

Comment: Thanks man, I was about to thank you before you updated the answer but now you give an example using it. It worked liked a charm, and thanks for clarifying things. :)

Comment: You're welcome, updated my answer with another possible import.

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
import Fiona from 'https://deno.land/x/fiona/deno/index.js'

var version = Fiona.version
console.log(version)
```

Found on the [documentation](https://github.com/billymoon/fiona#installation).

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot. This solved my problem too. Unfortunately I have already accepted the other answer as valid. But here is my upvote. Thanks for this man.